# how to conect a postgresql database to combobox on ruby form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, combobox

My question is this, I have my postgres database called gas_stations and only has a field called name, and I need that the form shows all the data in combobox from the table. also one of the options should appear "new station" and the truth I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you tale about table and not database. To do this, you must to create a model called GasStation like this :

```
class GasStation < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

After that, you could create a list in your view like this :

```
select("gas_station", "name", GasStation.all.collect {|gs| [ gs.name, gs.id ] }, { :include_blank => true })
```

See the guide here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

Comment: if I want that the option "new gasstation" appears how I can do that??

Comment: Try this : select("gas_station", "name", GasStation.all.collect {|gs| [ gs.name, gs.id ] } + ['New Gas Station', ''], { :include_blank => true })

Answer (score 0):

```
select("form_name", "gas_station_id", GasStation.all.collect {|g| [ g.name, g.id ] }, { :include_blank => true })
```

Something like this should get you started. Of course you need to create the Model etc ...

If you don't know how, use a quick tutorial to learn rails basics!